# How to solve RejectedExecutionException of AsyncTask?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, jobintentservice

I'm calling asyncTask from JobIntentService in following method

```
 public static void search(final String searchTerm, ApiCallback<SearchResult<Item>> apiCallback) {
        new SimpleTask<>(new SimpleTask.TaskAction<SearchResult<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public SearchResult<Item> doTask() {
                return new SearchResult<>(
                        searchTerm,
                        ArrayUtils.INSTANCE.concat(
                                SearchController.getSearch(Controller.DRUG, searchTerm)                    
                );
            }
        }, apiCallback).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
```

But getting following exception

```
 Caused by java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@fbb2c9 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@c1a8dce[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 22]
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2078)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:843)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1389)
           at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:651)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm calling asyncTask from JobIntentService

It is unlikely that this is a good plan.

Partly, that is because your `onHandleWork()` method is *already* on a background thread. You should not need a second one.

Partly, that is because the *point* of `AsyncTask` is to do work on the main application thread when background work is finished. There is no reason for a `JobIntentService` to be attempting to do work on the main application thread.

Partly, that is because your process might be stopped as soon as `onHandleWork()` returns, killing off your `AsyncTasks`.

> But getting following exception

You have started 137 tasks that are not yet completed, and there is a limit on how many pending `AsyncTasks` you can start.

Comment: @Ragini: Do not use `AsyncTask` from your `JobIntentService`.